# jQuery - creating date from input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, input

I really need your help to finish this

I'm working on my own script which import date from input which look like this:

```
<input type='text' class='hidden' value='$a' id='test'>
```

$a is date, taken from db with template(?): **2014, 03, 09, 04, 07, 02**

And its: **Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second**

So it looks like this

```
<input type='text' class='hidden' value='2014, 03, 09, 04, 07, 02' id='test'>
```

My javascript file is like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('input#test').removeClass('hidden');
    var a = $('input#test').val();
    console.log(a);
    var b = +new Date(a);
    console.log(b);
```

The 1st console log returns what input has (2014, 03, 09, 04, 07, 02), but the 2nd one returns NaN. I have no idea why :c

When I write it manually like this:

> var b = +new Date(2014, 03, 09, 04, 07, 02);

Its all working.. I have no idea how to solve it, I've also tried using this:

1. span and .html();
2. span and .text();

Any ideas? :)

Comment: a is a string so either you need to pull out the individual values to supply them as paramters to new Date(a[0], a[1] etc) or make the whole thing into a string ie. value = "Date(2014, 03, 09)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your a treated as string so it takes as first parameters of Date. You need to clarify other parameters in the Date. Why you are used + in the `new Date()`  ?

you have to take care one more thing month is started from 0 so 03 means April not March.

It seems that it is not needed.

try this:

```
 $('input#test').removeClass('hidden');
    var a = $('input#test').val();
    console.log(a);
    arr = a.split(",")
    var b = new Date(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[4],arr[5]);
    console.log(b);
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/55/)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing only one parameter (1 String) to the function! not 6!

use this:

> $(function() {
>       $('input#test').removeClass('hidden');
>
> ```
> var a = $('input#test').val();
>
> console.log(a);
>
> var params = a.split(", ")
>
> var b = +new Date(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4], params[5]);
>
> console.log(b);
> ```